# DownloadManager cursor attribute COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME is null when downloading fails

Tags: java, android, download, android-download-manager

I'm building a fallback for my `DownloadManager` which shall restart failed downloads.

I stuck to [vogella's](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/) example building my download manager functionality.

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

...

} else if (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED == c.getInt(columnIndex)) { 

         colIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);
         String localFilename = c.getString(colIndex);

}
```

The "failed"-case is working but my `localFilename` variable is `null`.

BTW: The `COLUMN_URI` is working.

Any ideas how I can access the target/local path or filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local filename is null because **downloading failed**.  There is no local file to reference.

Cf. the documentation for [`DownloadManager.html#getUriForDownloadedFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#getUriForDownloadedFile%28long%29) (emphasis added):

> Returns the Uri of the given downloaded file id, **if the file is downloaded successfully. Otherwise, null is returned**.

Answer (score 6):

The DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME field works since API 11, so if You are using older API the colIndex will be -1 and this will cause localFilename String to be null.

If you want to get path from the URI just

```
String path = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))).getPath()
```